# can I use mailto in <a> tage to open the body of outlook template?

Tags: c#, html, email, outlook

I have an outlook template, which is an email the user has saved.

I have also a `<a>` tag, i know that i can use the  tag to open the mail, with a body and a subject

my problem is that i just know how to send a text body, like this:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&cc=someone_else@example.com&body=This%20is%20the%20body">Send email</a>
```

i would like to know if there is any way to send html body

Comment: No, and you shouldn't want to.

Answer (score 0):

Section 2 of [RFC 2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) says that the body field is supposed to be in text/plain format, so you can't do HTML.

Comment: what shold i use please in order to send a real html body? what technologies? i am working with asp.net